# Converting web.config from IIS6 to IIS7 format

Tags: iis7, iis6

I'm a bit stuck, kinda been lumbered with a website developed over a year ago. The company that designed it and the company that own it dont now speak so I have been lumbered with trying to get it to work.

Bought the web space and have loaded it on to one of our sub domains while I get it working. Problem is that the Hosting provider is running ISS7 and the *web.config* was designed in IIS6 so am getting an error500 cause the tags are wrong. Could anyone give me some pointers on how to migrate the current web.config file over to IIS7.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways this can be done.  IIS7 introduced the integrated pipeline.  Many IIS6 developed applications can handle running as is in the IIS7 integrated pipeline, but for the ones that can't there are a couple of options for what can be done.  The easiest thing to do would be to switch the app pool the site or application is running to 'Classic' mode instead of using the integrated pipeline.  This will allow the application to be fully backwards compatible.  However, there are several IIS7 features you would not be able to take advantage of by running in Classic mode.

If that is not the best option for your situation then the web.config for the application will need to be converted to use the integrated pipeline.  You can go through this manually, or there is a command that can be run to convert a web.config to the IIS7 format:

Example:

%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/".

[Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis) is some additional information that might be helpful.